# commons-validator-1.4.1 Email validation fails

Tags: java

I am using `commons-validator 1.4.1 EmailValidator.isValid()`, and it returns that my email example@.com is correct, but is it really correct? I saw that there is small change in regular expression.

Thanks

Comment: I say that this is incorrect because there must be two level in the host portion of the address.

Comment: it was working in 1.3.1 version and now it is seems to be broken.. I did not found anything in release notes.

Comment: Having a look at the Release Notes I see areas where changes mights have let this invalid email address through; particularly in areas concerning TLD. I would file a bug report and get their expert opinion.

Comment: yes, you are correct, thanx. seems that it is passing for .com or com, but failing for others like test@t or test@.t , etc.

Comment: Try 1.5.0 version, Its working